# Make all In Caffe: could not find -l lmdbboost_system

Tags: makefile, caffe

The path is: /usr/local/caffe

When I run `sudo make all -j8`
I get an error:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llmdbboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:585: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I use caffe-cuda on ubuntu 18.04, cuda V10.0.130, nvcc V9.1.85, cuDNN V7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile

I forgot to add a space between lmdb and boost_system

```
LIBRARIES += lamdb boost_system
```